# save skim annotated pdf as pdf with annotations

Tags: preview, skim

I have skim version 1.4.16, and I can't find a way to save a pdf with skim notes as a pdf with annotations that preview 8.0 can read. I can export as a "pdf bundle", but preview 8.0 doesn't want to open such a file. I expect there are many other pdf readers, both in osX land and other OS's, that won't understand the bundle.

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skim doesn't save notes and highlights within the PDF file itself. That's why they don't show up in other viewers (much like 'bookmarks' in Preview).

It's possible to export a copy with notes and highlights embedded: `File > Export…` then choose file format **"PDF"** and mark the option **"With embedded notes"**. They will show up in Preview and Acrobat. However, Skim can't edit the notes of the exported copy anymore. Apparently, Preview and Acrobat can, though.

Skim FAQ at https://sourceforge.net/p/skim-app/wiki/FAQ/

(based on Skim version 1.4.18, OS X 10.7.5, Acrobat Pro XI)

Comment: Yep, that's what I missed! There are extra options when you export to "PDF" (: thx!

Comment: Is there a script to do this in batches?

Comment: @JessRiedel I don't know if there is already one available, but it is definitely possible to write a script and/or work with Automator to make a batch-export application. (I'm not versed enough in scripting to spontaneously hack one together.) Documentation: https://sourceforge.net/p/skim-app/wiki/AppleScript/

Comment: Thanks much!  I ended up finding an AppleScript solution in the question [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211428/need-script-to-automatically-export-skim-pdfs-with-embedded-notes/237587), but it didn't work for me so I hacked together a shell script and posted it as an alternative answer there.